# RHEL 7 - Crontab runs only under /etc/cron.d

Tags: cron

noobs here.
As my first step I edited the crontab as usually:

```
# crontab -e
0 2 * * * /root/backup.sh
```

The above, for some reason, never starts.
Instead, if I create a backup job under /etc/cron.d, the job is executed succesfully, e.g.

```
cron.d# cat backup
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
00 2 * * * root /root/backup.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This is not a problem for me, since I already solved the issue and cron job works now as expected, but I'm wondering why crontab on my RHEL 7 runs only under /etc/cron.d.

Any clue?

Thank you
Lucas

Comment: This is strange. `crontab -e` should setup the cron job. Have you looked into logs to get some clue what went wrong? `/var/log/messages` would be the place to look.

Comment: There is nothing on /var/log/messages, simply cron doesn't start while in crontab -e (crond service is running without issue). I got this behaviour on 4 RHEL 7 machines, but they are customized by vendor, so maybe they setup something that I don't understand

Comment: As which user you exec `crontab -e`?

Comment: Are the servers using access.config ?  There may be  exta permissions needed for crontab to work.  Check security log for errors when crontab tried to run it.

Comment: user is root.... there is no access.config... As I said this is not an issue since I used /etc/cron.d. I'm just curious on why /etc/crontab doesn't work